# Использование Progress Bar с датой

Tags: swift, xcode

Подскажите с вопросом, пожалуйста. Пытаюсь сделать Progress Bar, который заполняется полностью при достижении даты, которую выбрал юзер. Например, юзер выбрал дату 10 марта и выбрал конечную дату, например, 10 апреля. Таким образом, Progress Bar должен заполниться на 100% 10 апреля. Progress Bar находится в ячейке Table View, то есть у каждого Progress Bar может быть собственное значение.
Скорее всего, нужно использовать таймер, но я не понимаю как сконвертировать дату, которую выбрал юзер в нужный тип для заполнения Progress Bar. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее у вас должны быть даты которые выбрал юзер, переведенные в формат Date().

Имея их, сначала Вам нужно найти интервал (в секундах) между датой начала периода и датой окончания периода, используя метод timeIntervalSince. Например, получилось 500000 сек.

Теперь, при необходимости очередного отображения прогресс бара, вы находите текущую дату и (опять же с помощью timeIntervalSince) смотрите сколько секунд прошло от даты начала периода. Например, прошло 240000 секунд. После этого вы просто вычисляете, какой процент прогресс бара надо заполнить: 240000/500000 = 0,48. Если у вас нативный прогресс бар, то там есть параметр progress, устанавливаете его в 0.48 и у вас получается заполнено 48% прогресс бара. И так каждый раз при его отрисовке.

А таймер да, вы его используете для периодического обновления. По его сигналу производите расчет и перерисовку. Как часто, решать вам.